# CSS float property and block

Tags: css, css-float

I read this artical http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/.
I test it in my own chrome browser, yes, using float style generate the display:block style.
As I known display:block means that the element becomes the block-level element, and it occupies the whole line. Next element should starts in a new line.

But I test the float property. Although it generate the display:block, the next element(also float) is still  in the same line. So what's the matter with it?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    span
    {
        width: 30px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        background-color: Red;
        float:left;
    }
 </style>
<body>
<span>222</span><span>323</span><span>dd</span>
```

Comment: You have specified a width that is the problem. @roast_soul

Comment: based on your CSS and html, the elements will be inline as long as the body of the page is wider than 90px (3 x 30px).

Comment: My doubt is why it generates the display:block meanwhile it display as a inline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this blog, this might help you to understand more about float

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the float in order for the "floated" element to break to the next line. You can replace the span element with a div and you will see the same effect.

Comment: If we are clearing float after applying the same, why to use the float ? @roast_soul explanation about how float and display block works, I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you just want each of the spans to occupy a new line then give them each:

```
span { display:block; }
```

And remove:

```
span { float:left; }
```

A `div` would also accomplish this without css.